# Would I be able to change the date on my Greyhound ticket and depart on the same day?

Tags: tickets, greyhound

I'm going to visit a state across the country and found out at the last second that I'd be able to leave two weeks earlier than I thought I would be able to. I paid $81 for the economy ticket already, but my question is: would I be able to go into the station I am to depart from around 2 hours before the bus departs and have my ticket switched to leave that same day (same time, same destination, etc.)? The nearest station is around an hour and a half away. I am aware of the $20 fee for economy tickets. I would simply like to know if this would be at all possible or if I would get there and be denied doing so.

Comment: What did Greyhound say when you contacted them?

Comment: Call Greyhound customer service, then post the answer. 1 (214) 849-8966

Comment: OP hasn't returned to clarify questions. Putting on hold for now.